How can I get rid of the "File Access Denied"?
Please pardon my frustration, but Windows file access permissions is really extremely bad:
In SQL-Server Management Studio, I have used a stored procedure in order to create a trace file, something like:
DECLARE @TraceID INT;
DECLARE @MaxFileSize BIGINT = 50; -- File size limit in MB
DECLARE @TraceFilePath NVARCHAR(256) = N'C:\SQLTraces\Trace_OrderPart'; -- Base trace file path

-- Step 1: Create a new trace
EXEC sp_trace_create 
    @traceid = @TraceID OUTPUT,
    @options = 2, -- File rollover enabled
    @tracefile = @TraceFilePath,
    @maxfilesize = @MaxFileSize,
    @stoptime = NULL; -- No automatic stop

...

-- Step 4: Start the trace
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1; -- Start the trace

This has indeed created some so-called *.trc files, but when I try to open them, using SQL Server Profiler (see SSMS, "Tools" menu), this is what I get:

You might think: "No problem". Just copy the file elsewhere and open it there. This, however, does not work, so I am trying to modify directory file access: I start with this:

I uncheck the checkbox and click on "Apply changes to this folder, subfolders and files", I provide Administrator rights, he does the whole shebang and at the end, when I click on the directory again, this is (again) what I get:

I tried to force it using a WSL, but that doesn't work either:
"Who has access to this directory and what kind of access?"
Prompt>/mnt/c$ ls -ltra | grep "SQLTrace"
drwxrwxrwx 1 scampsd scampsd    4096 Dec  2 14:40 SQLTraces

=> "scampsd" has full access.
Who am I?
Prompt>/mnt/c$ cd ~
Prompt>~$ pwd
/home/scampsd

=> I AM "scampsd".
What can I do in order to force giving me access to that directory?

You are "scampsd" in WSL, but you're trying to delete/manage it in Windows (which isn't the same). In that WSL terminal you can likely open/manage the file as well

Access permissions are not controlled by the "Read-only" checkbox; they're controlled by the "Security" tab (or the icacls.exe tool).
Open "Security > Edit..." and add yourself with Modify or higher rights, or run:
icacls <path> /grant "<user>:(OI)(CI)(M)"

The (M) represents the "Modify" group of permissions, and the (OI)(CI) flags make the entry automatically inherited by all files and subfolders (thus explicit recursive change is usually not needed).

In your screenshot the "Read-only" checkbox is indeterminate because the graphical dialog never sets this attribute on directories, only on files (as the read-only flag has no effect on directories anyway and is repurposed for something else instead), so the dialog pretends that directories can't even be queried for its state. Either way, even if the files inside had this flag, it would only deny 'write' access but wouldn't stop you from opening the file for reading.
WSL2 runs as a VM guest and its access to /mnt/c is only through a filesystem proxy, which runs under your own Windows account and only has the same access as you do – no matter which Linux user does the access. The inability for WSL2 to bypass Windows access controls is intentional (even more so because the entire WSL2 VM is under your control, as that would otherwise turn it into a trivial security bypass).
The file permissions shown for /mnt/c in WSL are meaningless; there's no translation done from NTFS ACLs to Linux ACLs. (It would be a very lossy translation due to several mismatching semantics, anyway – even if you had used getfacl instead of ls -l, some things like inheritance or the 10+ fine-grained permissions cannot be expressed through "POSIX draft ACLs" that Linux implements. Some Unix-like systems implement NFSv4 ACLs which are 95% the same as Windows, but Linux unfortunately does not.)

you must use the command ACL or Icacls like Administrator to change the rights on a directory or file.
on prompt  DOS like  examples
file access permissions of the OS Windows is not suffisant.  You have
ACL like on UNIX OS ( AIX, SOLARIS,  OTHER )
E:\Users\pedro_2>cacls
REMARQUE : Cacls étant désapprouvé, utilisez Icacls.
Affiche/modifie les listes de contrôle d'accès des fichiers
CACLS nomfichier /T] [/M] [/L] [/S[:SDDL]] [/E] [/C] [/G util:perm]
[/R util [...]] [/P util:autor [...]] [/D util [...]]
nomfichier    Affiche les listes ACL.
/T  Modifie les listes ACL des fichiers dans
le répertoire et les sous-répertoires.
/L  Fonctionne sur le lien symbolique par opposition
à la cible
/M  Modifie les listes ACL des volumes montés dans un répertoire
/S  Affiche la chaîne SDDL pour la liste DACL.
/S:SDDL  Remplace les listes ACL par celles spécifiées dans
la chaîne SDDL (non valide avec /E, /G, /R, /P ou /D).
/E  Modifie la liste ACL au lieu de la remplacer.
/C  Continue la modif. des ACL et ignore les erreurs
/G util:autor Accorde des accès à l'utilisateur
Perm : R  Lecture
W  Écriture
C  Modification (en écriture)
F  Contrôle total
/R util       Révoque les accès de l'utilisateur
(valide uniquement avec /E).
/P util:autor Remplace les accès de l'utilisateur
Perm peut être : N  Aucun
R  Lecture
W  Écriture
C  Modification (en écriture)
F  Contrôle total
/D util       Refuse l'accès à l'utilisateur
Utilisez des caractères génériques pour spécifier plusieurs
fichiers dans une commande. Vous pouvez spécifier plusieurs utilisateurs
dans une commande.
Abréviations :
CI - Héritage de conteneur.
Les répertoires héritent de l'entrée de contrôle d'accès.
OI - Héritage d'objet.
Les fichiers héritent de l'entrée de contrôle d'accès.
IO - Héritage unique.
L'entrée de contrôle d'accès ne s'applique pas au fichier/répertoire
en cours.
ID - Hérité.
L'entrée de contrôle d'accès a hérité de la liste de contrôle
d'accès du répertoire parent.
E:\Users\pedro_2>
EXAMPLES :
cacls C:\VB2DelphiMigrationKit-master\ /E /T /C /G PIERRE39FF6BEE\Administrator:F
cacls c:\VBMIGRATIONKIT_DEVELOP\DelphiCollections1.0.4delphi_collections_1_0\ /E /T /C /G BUILTIN\Utilisateurs:F
cacls "C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7" /E /T /C /G PIERRE-39FF6BEE\Administrator:F
cacls c:\VBMIGRATIONKIT_DEVELOP\VB2DelphiMigrationKit-master*.* /E /T /C /G BUILTIN\Utilisateurs:F
HOPE THAT HELP YOU

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
